# Windows 8.1 won't start after malware cleaning

Tags: windows-8.1, malware

I've got my friend's laptop and was asked to clean it. After running `Malwarebytes`, `CCleaner`, `AdRemover` the Windows won't start.

Automatic repair doesn't work.

According to `Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt` the main reason is:

> Not found 234723482.sys file in system32 directory...

This file is obviously a fake sys file which was removed by the AdwCleaner, or Malwarebytes...

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: More than likely the bootloader has been patched by the malware, I suggest you back up important data and do a Clean Install of W8, this will guarantee its gone.

Answer (score 2):

I'd hazard a guess that it had a rootkit of some sort that integrated a file into the boot process, removing it broke the boot sequence.

Get a copy of a windows 8 disk or Bootable USB and use it to run SFC.exe. SFC can do an integrity check on the OS and use its "clean" copy of windows to repair the damaged install.